# drupal w CCK - how do I rename node submission buttons

Tags: forms, drupal, cck

I have made a custom node type for event registration. I have used themes (template.php to all a custom tpl.php for the form) to customise the look of the form.

Using workflow and actions / triggers, people can register for my event, and the event manager gets a notification email and can log in and see a view of who has registered. Neat!

It all works wonderfully, but I can't find a way to rename the default drupal node/add buttons - "save" and "preview" to say "submit registration" and "preview registration". Just a small thing, but quite important to user experience.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can do without writing a module and just add a custom theme function, as detailed in [this tutorial](http://adaptivethemes.com/using-hook-theme-to-modify-drupal-forms).

Basically you:

1. Find the form id
2. Create a *mytheme*`_form_id` theme function that alters the form returns drupal_render($form) (a little different from `hook_form_alter`)
3. Find the correct form element. I just dpm($form) and look for the result. I think in your case it should be in a 'buttons' array, but don't take my word for it.
4. Change the element.
5. Implement a *mytheme*`_theme` hook in your template.php that registers the above-mentioned function

Comment: While doable, this type of change should probably remain consistent across themes. The difference in technical complexity between changing it in the theme and changing it in a small module is minor.

Comment: Quote from the question: " I have used themes (template.php to all a custom tpl.php for the form) to customise the look of the form". That is - it's already highly customized. So, if anything, the opposite is true: it's better to put it all in the theme, rather than spread this single change out to a module.

Comment: That is, that change is an integral part of the theme, and therefore should stay within the theme. It's not about complexity (creating a hook_theme() is a little harder, if anything). Basically, it's for the reason you've mentioned: if the theme changes, that kind of thing (custom button labels) should change as well.

Comment: thanks, Eli. I think this fits the bill. I'll just have to find the right $form element.

Comment: For the record, the form element is

$form['buttons']['submit']['#value']

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You likely would want to use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) to alter the form and change the names of the submit buttons.

Unfortunately, you have to make a module to do this, because hook_form_alter() is not called on theme files.